# K-Fold for fit and prediction with sklearn Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

Is it possible to apply k-fold on fitting the model and later on predicting?

---

We have a structure built like the following, where data is trained upon time-series data between 2020-02-01 and 2021-02-01, and then tested on time-series data between 2021-04-01 and 2021-04-08, but unfortunately the results for predicting is very bad, and when we calculate the evaluation metrics, it is obvious something is wrong. Since we only have one year of data to train on, we might believe we are underfitting, and therefore we believe k-fold would help us.

[image]

What we want exactly is to k-fold on the period 2020-02-01 to 2021-02-01 and then afterwards predict on the period 2021-04-01 to 2021-04-08. By doing this, we efficiently train the model with the 1 year of data we have, and ensure a model fit to do a proper prediction. Is this possible, and perhaps an even better question to ask, is this the correct way of predicting data?

---

Our data looks like the following, where datetime is in %y%m%d format

```
datetime             temperature  solar   humidity   rain    temp_60
2020-02-01 00:00:00, 4.32,        22.84,  82.12,     16.36,  3.12
2020-02-01 00:10:00, 4.38,        21.99,  82.11,     16.25,  3.11
...
2021-11-01 00:00:00, 9.94,        15.43,  82.29,     14.83,  3.11
```

---

Code:

```
TargetVariable = ['temp_60']
predictors = ['temperature', 'humidity', 'rain', 'solar']
columnAll = ['datetime', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'rain', 'solar', 'temp_60', 'Predicted_temp_60', 'APE']

feature_selection_list = []

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Setting random seed for the initial starting weights
    rndseed = 7
    seed(rndseed)
    np.random.seed(rndseed)
    random.seed(rndseed)

    # Retrieve data from csv file
    dataframe = pd.read_csv("../data.csv")

    Algorithm(dataframe=dataframe)

def Algorithm(dataframe):

    # Split data
    dateToTrain = dataframe.loc[dataframe['datetime'].between('2020-02-01', '2021-02-01', inclusive=True)]
    dateToPredict = dataframe.loc[dataframe['datetime'].between('2021-04-01', '2021-04-08', inclusive=True)]

    # Initialize the pipeline
    estimator = pipelining()

    # Get values of the predictors and target variable for training data
    # For the datetime between 2020-02-01 and 2021-02-01
    X_train_year, y_train_year = dateToTrain[predictors].values, dateToTrain[TargetVariable].values

    # Get values of the predictors and target variable for testing data
    # For the datetime between 2021-04-01 and 2021-04-08
    X_test_all, y_test_all = dateToPredict[predictors].values, dateToPredict[TargetVariable].values

    # ...
    ann = ArtificialNeuralNetwork(predictors=predictors, pipeline=estimator, X_train=X_train_year, y_train=y_train_year)
    annPredictionDataframe = ann.modelFitAndPredict(X_test=X_test_all, y_test=y_test_all)

    # ...
    annPredictionDataframe['datetime'] = dateToPredict['datetime'].values
    kfold_score = ann.evaluateScoreKFold()
    annPredictionDataframe = annPredictionDataframe[columnAll]

    # Evaluation of the performance of the Artificial Neural Network (ANN)
    evaluation = performanceEvaluation(y_test_orig=annPredictionDataframe['temp_60'], y_test_pred=annPredictionDataframe['Predicted_temp_60'])

    evaluation["Generalization Error"] = kfold_score.mean()

def pipelining():

    # Standardizing the features
    estimators = [('standardize', StandardScaler())]
    estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=make_regression_ann, batch_size=10, epochs=100)))

    # The pipeline can be used as any other estimator
    # and avoids leaking the test set into the train set
    pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)

    return pipeline

def make_regression_ann(initializer='uniform', activation='relu', optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mae', neurons=12):
    inputDim = len(predictors) if selection == 1 or selection == 3 or selection == 4 else len(tmp)

    # create ANN model
    model = Sequential()

    # Defining the Input layer and FIRST hidden layer, both are same!
    # model.add(Dense(units=neurons, input_dim=len(feature_selection_list), kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation, activity_regularizer=l1(0.0001)))
    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, input_dim=inputDim, kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation, activity_regularizer=l1(0.0001)))

    # Defining the Second layer of the model
    # after the first layer we don't have to specify input_dim as keras configure it automatically
    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation))

    # The output neuron is a single fully connected node
    # Since we will be predicting a single number
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer))

    # Compiling the model
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    return model

def performanceEvaluation(y_test_orig, y_test_pred):
    evaluationColumns = ['Coefficient of Determination (R2)', 'Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)', 'Mean Squared Error (MSE)', 'Mean Absolute Percent Error (MAPE)', 'Mean Absolute Error (MAE)', 'Mean Bias Error (MBE)']

    # Computing the Mean Absolute Percent Error
    MAPE = mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test_orig, y_test_pred)

    # Computing R2 Score
    r2 = r2_score(y_test_orig, y_test_pred)

    # Computing Mean Square Error (MSE)
    MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test_orig, y_test_pred)

    # Computing Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)
    RMSE = mean_squared_error(y_test_orig, y_test_pred, squared=False)

    # Computing Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
    MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_test_orig, y_test_pred)

    # Computing Mean Bias Error (MBE)
    MBE = np.mean(y_test_pred - y_test_orig)  # here we calculate MBE

    eval_list = [r2, RMSE, MSE, MAPE, MAE, MBE]

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame([eval_list], columns=evaluationColumns)

    return dataframe
```

In a seperate file. This is where we do the fit and prediction:

```
class ArtificialNeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, predictors, pipeline, X_train, y_train):
        self.predictors = predictors
        self.pipeline = pipeline
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train

    def evaluateScoreKFold(self):

        cv = KFold(n_splits=10)
        results = cross_val_score(self.pipeline, X=self.X_train, y=self.y_train, cv=cv, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error")

        print(f'Cross Validation Results: {results}')
        print("Standardized: % .2f( % .2f) MAE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

        return results

    def modelFitAndPredict(self, X_test, y_test):

        # THIS IS WHERE WE SHOULD PROBABABLY DO KFOLD WITH THE ONE YEAR DATA TO TRAIN UPON THIS PIPELINE. IS THIS CORRECTLY ASSUMED???
        self.pipeline.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

        # Generating Predictions on testing data
        Predictions = self.pipeline.predict(X_test)

        TestingData = pd.DataFrame(data=X_test, columns=self.predictors)
        TestingData['temp_60'] = y_test

        TestingData['Predicted_temp_60'] = Predictions
        TestingData.head()

        # Computing the absolute percent error
        APE = 100 * (abs(TestingData['temp_60'] - TestingData['Predicted_temp_60']) / TestingData['temp_60'])
        TestingData['APE'] = APE

        # Rounding all floats to 2 decimals
        TestingData = TestingData.round(2)

        TestingData.to_csv("TestingData.csv")

        return TestingData
```

---

The Evaluation Metrics:

```
Generalization Error  R2        RMSE    MSE     MAPE   MAE    MBE
0.921                 -327.534  6.945   48.229  0.811  5.212  1.835
```

Comment: It is not clear what *exactly* your question is; K-Fold CV is *not* used to prevent over/underfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of cross-validation (K-fold) is **model checking**, not model building.

Once you have checked with cross-validation that you obtain similar metrics for every split, you have to train your model with **all** your training data.

Maybe, what you are looking for is [ensemble methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html). But I'm not sure if they can be applied with NN. A clear example is Random forest: many decision trees algorithm are trained and evaluated.

Finally, just comment that with NN, in general, as more data you have, better knowledge you obtain, so maybe splitting data to obtain different models is not the best option.

Comment: Have i misunderstood cross-validation (K-fold) if i believe that we can train the model with k-folding and then whenever knowing which model has the lowest error, we use that model on the testing data? Right now it seems like what i am doing is hold-out, where i beforehand declare training data and test data. Our thought is that is if we k-fold instead of hold-out on the data, then maybe we will receive better results. Is this not correct? And i apologize beforehand for my lack of knowledge in this field